# Mapbox-gl – rendering static map based on bounds?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a Mapbox rendered in my browser, where the canvas is `400px` wide and `300px` tall (set using CSS).
What I want to be able is to get a static representation of what I see in the screen using [this mapbox API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#retrieve-a-static-map-from-a-style) with the highest possible resolution, preserving the aspect ratio. I know that the maximum value passed to this API is `1280px` hence the calculations:

```
const api_width = 1280;
const api_height = (300 * 1280) / 400;
```

I can get the centre of the map with the current zoom using MapBox API, but when I pass those values to the static map generator API, I get an image that's not properly adjusted (it's probably about the zoom).

How can I make sure that the static image I generate from the API looks exactly the same as what I see on the screen in my browser (with different canvas size)?

I thought about retrieving my map's bounds using `getBounds` method, but what should I do to recalculate those north-east and south-west bounds to pass the values to the static api?

**My canvas:**
[image]
**Static API resut:**
[image]

I've also found this API now and passed my center lat and lng along with my zoom and current canvas dimensions to the `.bounds()` method. Then I grabbed the output and passed the bounds to the `.viewport()`. The results were passed to the static API and I got something that's pretty close, but it's not perfect:

```
const { lat, lng } = map.getCenter();
const zoom = map.getZoom();
const bounds = MapBoxGeo.bounds([lng, lat], zoom, [400, 300);
const viewport = MapBoxGeo.viewport(bounds, [1280, 960]);
```

[image]

The `center` and `zoom` values I get from my browser's map are:

```
const lat = 40.710590956829776;
​const lng = -74.00707253662097;
const zoom = 13.064434392733872
```

Comment: What do you mean "not properly adjusted"? Include examples?

Comment: @SteveBennett I've edited my origin post and added the results I got, along with the results when I used mapbox's geoviewport api

Comment: Ok, I see where my problem is. I've set the width and height using CSS, and the canvas still has its height and width html attributes set. This is where the issue is.